# Qt, не могу наследоваться от QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt6

добрые люди. Что, собственно происходит?

Пытаюсь отнаследоваться от класса QOpenGLWidget, а оно не хочет.

Насколько я понимаю, мой класс почему-то считается абстрактным, поэтому его экземпляр и не создается. Все методы openGL переопределены.

Дошёл  до того, что просто взял из интернета код и вставил в свою qt. Тоже не работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Ниже оставляю файл pro и реализацию своего несчастного класса (у меня Qt самая новая, с официального сайта)

```
QT       += core gui
QT += opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION,5): QT += core5compat
CONFIG += c++11


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS +=

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target



#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtOpenGLWidgets/QOpenGLWidget>

class gl : public QOpenGLWidget {

public:
    gl(QWidget *parent = NULL) : QOpenGLWidget(parent) {}
    ~gl() {}

protected:
    virtual void initializeGL() override { }

    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h) override {
        Q_UNUSED (w)
        Q_UNUSED(h)
    }
    virtual void paintGL() override {}

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    gl wnd;

    wnd.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас версия `Qt6.0+`, тогда надо подключать модуль `openglwidgets` ([док](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html)):

```
QT += openglwidgets
```

Рекомендую также переименовать класс gl во что-то более подходящее и перенести его в отдельный файл (`.h` и `.cpp`). Не забудьте также указать макрос `Q_OBJECT`

```cpp
class MyOpenGLWidget: public QOpenGLWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
...
}
```